# Read a Object with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I have an object created from a JSON

```
{"date": "11/21/2018", "nick": "abcd"}
```

When reading it with

```
const xUrl = 'https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/usuarios.json?orderBy="nick "';
     return this.http.get (xUrl) .pipe (
       map (res => {
         return res;
         console.log (res);
        })
     );
```

The result of console.log (res); is a Object :

```
-LRqtDl09Sc1J4K4IOln:
      date: "11/21/2018"
      nick: "abcd"
```

I need to know the number of returned results and if there are results, take the Nick field

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys({"date": "11/21/2018", "nick": "abcd"}).length` 
will allow you to check if any properties where passed back. So if the length is greater than 0 you have results and then you can check how many were actually passed. I hope I understood your question correctly.